# What tools exist for organizing the most recent papers covering a specific topic?

Tags: literature-search

Inspired by the recent post, [How can I be up-to-date on recent papers, practically?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/196085/how-can-i-be-up-to-date-on-recent-papers-practically), I want to know what tools exist for finding recent papers (pre-print and published) on specific topics.

The recent post focused on how to stay up-to-date on a field, in general. Many of these answers provide helpful tools when trying to stay up-to-date on a broad field. (For example, [benty-fields](https://www.benty-fields.com) provides a nice daily arXiv display, but can only filter by broad, pre-defined terms). I am interested in a tool (like a website) that can organize papers published on topics that I can specify with a search term. I am not looking for email alerts.

The best thing I have found has been a Google Scholar search with custom keywords, filtered by most recent. If this is the best tool for my specific case, I can work with it. However, it would be ideal to not have to redo this search every day or deal with Google Scholar's slow indexing. Additionally, if the tool has more features, like saving to a "read later" list, that would also be great.

Does anyone have any tips?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you do not want to use email alerts? You can request email updates based on defined searches in many of the aggregate search engines. It would be easy to automatically separate these emails into a dedicated folder and peruse them at your leisure. You may consider using RSS feeds in conjunction with a reader program. Many journals and databases still provide RSS feeds that summarize recent publications (though this a bit of a dated method and likely even less convenient and flexible than email).

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you're looking for, since you hav exlcuded email alerts and you acknowledge that a database (e.g., Google Scholar) search with a set of custom search terms does the job. When you say, "it would be ideal to not have to redo this search every day", what's the difference between than and an email alert? And I don't understand what you mean by "Google Scholar's slow indexing". I don't think you will find any source that updates the most recently published work faster than Google Scholar. Please rewrite your question to clarify what you are looking for.

Comment: Perhaps you could rewrite your question by describing what exactly this tool you are looking for would do and clarifying in detail how Google Scholar's email alerts do not do what you want.